# Registering an app with Twitter require prior to its development

Tags: twitter

I want to develop a Twitter web application on GAE/J. So for that first I need to register an app with Twitter on http://twitter.com/apps/new before I go for development? Do I require some token or keys from twitter before development. That token or keys will only be generated when we give our (production) URL to it.

It means I need to have .com (production URL) to start it?

Can you guys guide in this? I am going right way to start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we do need to create consumer key and consumer secret key by giving our URL to Twitter on http://twitter.com/apps/new. For that GAE/J appspot URL will work. Got it.